# SQL query to return the employee details in departments that have more than 5 employees

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the two tables below; I’m trying to create a query that returns the employee details in departments that have more than 5 employees

```
Employee{empNo, firstName, lastName, city, street, postCode, sex, dob, nin, dateJoined, deptNo}

Department{deptNo, phoneNo, faxNo, city, street, postCode, mgrempNo, startDate}
```

I can return a simple list that returns the departments with more than 5 employees but I’m unsure how to add the employee details to this?

Do I even need 2 tables or a join if deptNo is a foreign key in the Employee table?

I have a feeling I need 2 queries (possible sub query) and somehow need to link them

Hoping to return a list with the all the column headings in the employee table

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It should return all of the employee information in Employee for any employee in a department with more than 5 employees:

```
SELECT e.*, d.vol as employeeCount 
FROM Employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT d1.deptNo, count(*) as vol
    FROM Department d1
    JOIN Employee e1 on (d1.deptNo = e1.deptNo)
    GROUP BY d1.deptNo
    HAVING count(*) > 5
) d on (e.deptNo = d.deptNo)
```

Comment: this worked for me - I am just trying to understand the e1 and d1 and vol parts for my own development - but the statement worked

Comment: e1, d1 are just aliases used in the join query.  You could use anything there.  An alias is just a convenient label you can use to make referring to a table or field simpler.  I used e1 and d1 to differentiate from e and d used in the top level query, but it's not necessary.  Aliases are often seen like this: FROM Employee AS e, but the "AS" isn't necessary, so it gets left out a lot, and you just put the alias directly after whatever you are aliasing.

Comment: There's no need to join `department` table because you do not use any information from it. `WHERE e1.deptno is not null` is sufficient (if your database is not broken by non-existing references to `department` table).

Comment: I didn't use window functions because it's not clear what version or even flavor of SQL is targeted here. For instance, mySQL doesn't support window functions until 8.0. Without window functions there is going to have to be a join to get the counts, but you're right that department isn't needed, and it is probably more performant if you join to the aggregate query on employee, but I bet that you'll never notice the difference unless those tables are really large and I also bet at some point they're going to want to pull some information from department.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             count(*) over (partition by deptid) as num_employees
      from employee e
     ) e
where num_employees > 5;
```

Note that the department table is not needed.

If you didn't want to use window functions, there are other methods such as:

```
select e.*
from employee e join
     (select deptid, count(*) as num_employees
      from employee e2
      group by deptid
     ) ed
     on ed.deptid = e.deptid
where num_employees > 5;
```